# City after name of city capitalized

Tags: grammar

I am aware that when referring to "the City of," you should capitalize the word "city." I am just wondering, do you still capitalize the word "city" if it comes after the name of the city rather than before?

This was a direct quote I am writing so I cannot change the way it was said. But the person said "Albany city said we could recruit there." He is referring to a school district in the City of Albany. Would city be capitalized? Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Unless "city" is part of the name (i.e. "Carson City" or "New York City"), it's not capitalized after the city's name.  Even used before (as in "City of"), the capitalization only happens if the title of the city in question actually has that name ("City of London", "City of New York").

Comment: I would capitalize it where *city* is used as a distinguishing marker: *They lived in Baltimore City at first but moved to Baltimore County when their son was born*. This is the practice of the City of Baltimore as well as the *Baltimore Sun*. This is also common usage for Virginia's cities: *Alexandria City* to distinguish the *City of Alexandria* from the adjacent parts of Fairfax County which are also called, and receive mail addressed to, *Alexandria, Virginia*; or *Fairfax City* to distinguish that municipality from the geographically enveloping but politically separate *Fairfax County*.

Comment: Of course, when the political distinction is not important, no marker is used at all; it is simply "I'm from Baltimore" or "I live in Fairfax." I also acknowledge that this usage varies by region; no one ever says *Los Angeles City* or *San Diego City*.

Answer (score 0):

It is never correct to capitalize a municipality preceding the word "of." As noted in the second reply, local customary use may not follow rules of grammar. As noted in the first reply, if you insist on correct cpaitalization of a municipality (city, village, town, township), it is “village of” XYZ. If used in a title, such as Village of XYZ Comprehensive Plan, then the rules of capitalization say upper case because it is a noun in a title. Same with the beginning of a sentence: Village residents enjoy popcorn. Or a label on a map, title on a village seal or other graphic, list in a table or chart, and a few other limited circumstances, such as a police badge that is basically also a municipal seal, or Table of Contents, which is a specialized table. Same goes for the nouns city and town. But that doesn’t mean it is okay to capitalize village of Marathon in every sentence. Only in the title, Village of Marathon Revitalization Plan because that is the name of the document. Because village of Marathon is not a place, Marathon is the place, you don’t capitalize village. Ever. It is a place called Marathon that happens to be a village. Sometimes, an adjacent village, town, or city might have the same name, as in Cazenovia, NY. The “town” of and “village” of small letter rule still applies. Both levels of government are still just named Cazenovia.

In English, any part of government followed by the word “of” is not capitalized:  “We went around the state of New Jersey.” The exception for city, town, hamlet, state, or village is when the part of government is actually part of the place name. Johnson City. New York City. I don’t think any town, hamlet, or village in NY has town or village as part of the place name. But Greenwich Village might be an example if it were actually a village and not just a Manhattan neighborhood.  Even references to the neighborhood are capitalized, the ”Village.”

County is always capitalized because it is part of the place name. Same with our State. We are in New York State, so State is always capitalized in a sentence because it refers to New York State and is shorthand for the full name. There is no such place as New Jersey State. Nor Massachusetts State, Pennsylvania State (both commonwealths, actually) but you see what I mean?

Even if you Google it up, you need to be aware of the sources you research. A limited few have it wrong!  Reputable sources and the overwhelming majority will validate the proper prohibition on use of capitalization for the phrase “municipality of XYZ.” Once you realize it, you can’t unsee it and you’ll notice lots of errors in common writing. As this is technical writing, I feel that it should also show knowledge of basic correct English usage even if it takes a little getting used to. Notice this is not the same as nit-picking grammar such as ending a sentence with a preposition or using who instead of whom. People commonly make grammar errors that sound better in spoken language. But reading is harder if you have to bulldoze past capitalization errors sixty times in a document. Incorrect capitalization is basically a typo once you recognize it. Conversely, correctly not capitalizing the municipal entity (village, town or city in NY) gives confidence that you know what you are writing about. You might even see Microsoft correcting you to drop the capitalization if you use the latest updated version of Ms Word.

One more footnote on this topic. Lawyers are in the habit of capitalizing all sorts of nouns. It’s like they are German or something. Planners often copy legal jargon and affectations, since lots of planning practice is underpinned in case law or common law. Thus, unfortunately, “plannerese” “language” used by professional planners tends to perpetuate the capitalization error preceding the word “of.” But really we are using the English language, therefore, bound by the rules of English grammar.

The reason you see inconsistencies, such as approved LWRPs, comp plans, zoning, building standards, form-based codes, etc. with “Village of”  or “Village”, “Town of” or “Town”, “City of” or “City”  capitalized in every sentence is because planning documents are written and reviewed by people ignorant of correct grammar, professional planners with an agenda to further the use of plannerese jargon,  attorneys accustomed to randomly capitalizing nouns, or folks who are simply following a pattern of prior other documents without thinking much about what they are writing. I’m pretty sure we can do better than that without a lot of effort. Not trying to be professionally superior, just a straightforward good technical writer. I urge you to consider making this a pert of your style manual unless specifically directed to do otherwise by a client. Even then, it may be worth some push back given the likely sources of their insistence which has no basis in English.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If the actual official name of the municipality is *CIty of XXX*, as it is in the [City of Los Angeles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles), then of course you need to capitalize "city".